# scope javascript code embedded through SRC

Tags: javascript

I need to scope JavaScript code.
I know I can do it using

```
(function() {
    // all code goes here
})();
```

enclose all mycode within an anonymous function.

but how do I do it if I have page that loads JS through script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jsFile}"></script>
```

JavaScript from that load breaks my page, how do I enclose it?

Thanks

Comment: In the file you're loading...

Comment: Try adding `alert("yo")` to the file you're including to see if the file is being included properly...

Comment: The external file you reference uses the same names in the global namespace that your code does? I'm guessing here. The defense is to namespace your own variables & function names so that 3rd party code can't stomp yours.

Comment: How does it break your page?

Comment: it just does not work. Many errors. loaded script has more 100 000 lines of code. It does work if I take a script put on my page and enclose it. But I can not do it for production, I did it for test

Comment: Then you also can solve the problem by enclosing your own scripts. If you have done that properly and still get errors, please come back with more detailed information (e.g. error messages) and we can help you

Answer (score 2):

Do the same thing....

In the JS file just surround it with the

```
(function() {
    // all code goes here
})();
```

and you *should* be good....

Comment: tried it. Did not work.

Comment: @antohoho: then you need to describe your problem in more detail than "did not work". We're not psychic.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not have access to JS, thats why I do src.

Comment: @antohoho what are you trying to include?

Comment: I am trying to include JavaScript code, and he conflicts with my JS. so I am trying to enclose him. it does work with (function() {})() but I cant do it because I do not have access. So I need to find a way to do it when I load it via SRC

Comment: @antohoho: Please [be more specific](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17409603/edit) about how that script file conflicts with your code. There are other solutions than "scoping" it.

Comment: I explained, I have script <script type="text/javascript" src="${jsFile}"></script>. It does not work with my. I can not change anything but enclose  <script type="text/javascript" src="${jsFile}"></script> somehow that script. If I would have code on a page I would put in inside (function() {})() and it does work. But I cant do it if I load via SRC